# Where can I ask questions about having Arabic text translated?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I don't know Arabic, and I would like this picture translated:

[image]

What site should I ask this question on?

Comment: Usually the language sites at SE don't serve as translation services, even if we would have a site for arabic language. Check https://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation-traffic

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Then where should I ask it? Who does offer translation services?

Comment: _"Who does offer translation services?"_ Google. Maybe Reddit or Quora.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't have an Arabic keyboard, and I don't know how to type those symbols into google trasnlate.

Comment: _"I don't have an Arabic keyboard, and I don't know how to type those symbols into google trasnlate"_ Maybe try an OCR program to get the plain text..

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Modern AI hasn't gotten to that point yet.

Comment: That's not a matter of AI, just simple OCR.

Comment: Google translate in a browser lets you draw the characters. There's also a camera mode in the app now (at least on Android).

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is:  none of the Stack Exchange sites offer actual *translation* of the text you're looking at.

Google Translate, which is available on most modern phone OSes, offers in-situ OCR of text like this.  You may get a better result from scanning that than I did in looking at your third-hand picture (something about a dog and a curse...).

Answer (score 0):

There is [no site on Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) that is for the Arabic language, therefore it won’t be answered on the network.

Your best shot is to ask the question somewhere else as suggested in the comments or use Google Translate as *Makoto* suggested.